# Solution to ODE $y'y^2+yy''-(y')^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve $y'y^2+yy''-(y')^2=0$

My first thought was to substitute $y''=p$ yet I would not know what to do with $y$. I am out of ideas how to approach this problem.

Comment: the solution Looks terrible, have you tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: @Dr.SonnardGraubner: are you sure you plugged it in correctly? Wolfram Alpha seems to output the relatively simple solution of $\frac{ae^{x+ab}}{e^{ax+ab}-1} $

Comment: I get the same answer using Wolfram Alpha, but I have no idea how to get it without using computer

Comment: Divide the equation by $y^2$ and observe that it can be integrated ... indeed the second integration is also quite easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$, then $y''=\frac{d}{dx}v=y'\frac{dv}{dy}=y'v'=vv'$

So the equation becomes $$y^2v+yvv'-v^2=0\implies y^2+yv'-v=0\implies v'-\frac{v}{y}=-y$$

Then multiplying through by $1/y$ using integrating factor method gives $$\frac d{dy}\left(\frac{v}{y}\right)=-1\implies v=ky-y^2$$

Next we need to solve the DE $$y'=ky-y^2$$
This can be solved as follows: $$\int\frac {y'}{ky-y^2}dx=\int1dx\\ \int\frac1{(k-y)y}dy=x+c\\ \frac1k\int\frac1{y}+\frac1{k-y}dy=x+c\\\log y-\log (k-y)=kx+c\\y=\frac{ke^{kx+c}}{e^{kx+c}+1}$$

> Wolfram Alpha:
>   $$y(x)=\frac{ke^{kx+c}}{e^{kx+c}-1}$$

I appear to have lost a minus sign somewhere :(

But close enough, I'm sure someone will spot the error.